# Armature Changes Pose From Object to Edit Mode

Tags: rigging

[image]

Red Bar is to show the original positioning of where the elbow started in Object mode. Top Arm is in Object Mode, Bottom Arm is in Edit Mode. I just created a character in Adobe Fuse, took the .obj and uploaded it into mixamo.com where it was rigged and downloaded as an .fbx. Instantly import the .fbx into Blender and have this issue. I've created clothing for my NPCs, I'm trying to rig them all to the character. I just did this whole process with a male and didn't have this issue. I believe I did everything EXACTLY the same. A bit confused on how this could happen or how to fix it? I can reset one of the modes positions to Rest Position, which fixes the switching of different poses, but doesn't work trying to rig clothing to the character in Blender. Anybody ever run into this problem? Any help, guidance or anything would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Afaik mixamo will set the default keys to a tpose. Do any of your pose bones have any rotations?

Comment: Yes actually they do

Comment: Well, if the pose bones are rotated, then a difference in edit mode and pose mode is expected, isn't it?

Comment: Oh sorry I think I might have misunderstood. Did you mean, did I pose the bones? If so no, the character is still in T pose mode but the bones are rotated when I look through the settings

Comment: If there are rotations on the pose bones, they're **pose** in pose mode is naturally going to be different than their *pose* in **edit mode**. In edit mode, poses are not shown, otherwise you couldn't edit the bones. Mixamo automatically poses the bones(!). If you want to have the same pose in pose mode and edit mode you have to reset the transformations and delete the transformation keyframes.